# PDF form created with Adobe LiveCycle Designer 8.0 - Form checkboxes randomly submitted as null values

Tags: pdf, xml

I have a data collection process where users complete a PDF form and then submit an xml data file of the form values via email. I've had nearly 600 files submitted - the process has worked exactly as planned for about 550 of them.

For about 50 files I there are null values for some of the fields, mostly checkboxes. The checkboxes are not mandatory, but do have a default value (Off). So in most cases, where the user has not ticked a box I am getting the right result - an 'Off' value.

The files with Null values may have all come from the same user or office, although this is difficult to confirm as the data is anonymous.

The dilemma I have is whether or not to count the Nulls as Off values (i.e. box not ticked) or whether some or all are actually supposed to be On values (i.e. box ticked, but for some reason cleared when sent).

The form was created in Adobe LiveCycle Designer 8.0 and is being completed in Adobe Reader by users.

Any information or insight about why or how this might be happening would be useful, as I'll have to factor it into my data analysis somehow anyway.